# Testing Native iOS app on one phone works, but crashes on another phone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, sigabrt

I have built an app that will open on my iPhone, but will not open on my employer's phone.

XCode reports that "[APP NAME] could not be opened" every time I try to run it on my employer's phone.  A SIGABRT was reported.

Any ideas as to why it wouldn't load on one phone, while it will on another?

Comment: Delete the app on both phones. Clean the Xcode project. Restart both phones. Install fresh on each. If it still crashes only on one I'd start looking at version numbers, GSM vs CDMA, corrupted device profiles, etc.

Comment: Please edit your question and the output from your console log.

Comment: Are the phones the same model? Different models have different capabilities and resources.

Comment: Take a look at crash log, [symbolicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html), and see if you can figure out where it crashed and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your employer's iPhone belong to the same development team profile as yours?

Comment: Yeah, all of that matches up. Correct dev provisioning profile. It has run other apps in the past.

Comment: Could there be another app on the phone using the same app id?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:
1. log in to Dev Center
2. go to "iOS Provisioning Portal" (link on the right)
3. click "Provisioning" on the left
4. edit->modify the provisioning profile you are trying to use

Is your employer's device checked?